# How to represent only month in <time datetime=""> attribute?

Tags: html

```
<time datetime="1914">  <!-- means the year 1914 -->
<time datetime="1914-12">  <!-- means December 1914 -->
<time datetime="1914-12-20">  <!-- means 20 December 1914 -->
<time datetime="12-20">  <!-- means 20 December any year -->
```

But, how to represent only month in `<time datetime="">` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a look at the Mozilla Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time).

It is mentioned to use `2011-11` as ***a valid month string***

That means it would be something like `YYYY-MM`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear possible to represent a "yearless month" similar to the ["yearless date"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#yearless-dates) if that's what you're asking